# pytesseract-no such file or directory error

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I have the following code:

```
import Image
import pytesseract
im = Image.open('test.png')
print pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/chaitanya/pythonapp/localcopy.py", line 4, in <module>
    print pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 142, in image_to_string
    config=config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 75, in run_tesseract
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Both the python program and the image are in the same location.What could be the problem??

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to install `tesseract-ocr`:

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough! This error message was so generic, I would never ever thought tesseract was missing. (for CentOS: `yum install tesseract`)

Comment: for macOS you should run `brew install tesseract`.
if you don't have brew installed, check this out: [Brew Package Manager](https://brew.sh/)

Answer (score 4):

If you're on windows and have PIP installed go to your project directory and run:

`pip install tesseract-ocr`

Answer (score 3):

Based off of @padraic cunningham's answer which I tailored to my setting.

If you are on Linux (ubuntu 16, should not matter) and have a conda installation:

First search for what you need to be installing:

```
$ anaconda search -t conda tesserocr
```

You will get a few options, you need to look at the platforms and builds to identify what makes sense for you.

As I have python 3.6 and linux-64 I chose mcs07/tesserocr

To install:

```
$ conda install -c mcs07 tesserocr
```

That's it. I didn't need a restart of the terminal or anything. I just kept going.