# leptonica/allheaders.h file not found (gcc error) on install of tesseract-ocr

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract, pytesser

I am trying to run the following code on my mac.

```
import Image
import pytesseract

im = Image.open('test.png')
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(im))
```

Following the question from here: [pytesseract-no such file or directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741563/pytesseract-no-such-file-or-directory-error)
I need to install tesseract-ocr

but when I try to pip install tesseract-ocr I get the following errors:

```
creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I//anaconda/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g
-fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I//anaconda/include/python2.7 -c
tesseract_ocr.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/tesseract_ocr.o
tesseract_ocr.cpp:264:10: 
fatal error: 'leptonica/allheaders.h' file not found #include "leptonica/allheaders.h"
     ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: You need to install a C library that should be available here http://www.leptonica.org/download.html ; if you are using brew, `brew install leptonica` might help.

Comment: I tried `pip install leptonica` but received another error   `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement leptonica (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for leptonica`

Comment: If `pip install leptonica` was possible, `pip install tesseract-ocr` would do that automatically.

Answer (score 15):

You need install `libtesseract-dev` in your system;

```
sudo apt install libtesseract-dev
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! worked.

Answer (score 2):

Use this with yum:

```
yum install leptonica-devel tesseract-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

In Linux Use the Following Command

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

Answer (score 1):

refer [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875597/cant-install-tesseract-ocr-on-mac), final **solution** on my Mac:

`brew install tesseract`

**explanation**:

it will install backend `tesseract` and dependent lib `leptonica` (and others libs: `giflib, jpeg, libpng, libtiff, little-cms2, openjpeg, webp`), so can fix this error.

Comment: I was still getting an error after doing this. Before using tesseract in code, I had to set the path of my tesseract installation to a variable, as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54995964/14068350

Answer (score 0):

try it like this without using space in between
"pip install easyocr"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).