# Can't install Tesseract-OCR on Mac

Tags: python-2.7, tesseract

I'm trying to make an OCR program in python 2.7.14 with pytesseract. When I ran my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png')))
```

I got the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.png'
```

I searched in many places, and it seems that I need to install tesseract-ocr. I ran:

```
pip install tesseract-ocr
```

But I got the error:

Collecting tesseract-ocr
  Using cached tesseract-ocr-0.0.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: cython in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tesseract-ocr)
Installing collected packages: tesseract-ocr
  Running setup.py install for tesseract-ocr ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/rd/lf95py7d7s3dkzft38jh3m8h0000gn/T/pip-build-DTR_fL/tesseract-ocr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/rd/lf95py7d7s3dkzft38jh3m8h0000gn/T/pip-U3OoHi-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
    file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
    running build_ext
    building 'tesseract_ocr' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c tesseract_ocr.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/tesseract_ocr.o
    tesseract_ocr.cpp:558:10: fatal error: 'leptonica/allheaders.h' file not found
    #include "leptonica/allheaders.h"
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/rd/lf95py7d7s3dkzft38jh3m8h0000gn/T/pip-build-DTR_fL/tesseract-ocr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/rd/lf95py7d7s3dkzft38jh3m8h0000gn/T/pip-U3OoHi-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/rd/lf95py7d7s3dkzft38jh3m8h0000gn/T/pip-build-DTR_fL/tesseract-ocr/

Is there anyway I can fix this?
(This same error occurred when I tried other ways of installing it, like sudo)

Comment: Are you running it from the same directory where test.png is?

Comment: Could you please add the exact command that you use for running the script?

Comment: To be honest, i'm not quite sure. I'm running this short program in terminal, and I have a picture named 'test.png' on my desktop, so would that be in the same directory?

Comment: To run this program, I open terminal, then type "Python", then I type in my code

Comment: Copy your Python script (say it's called myscript.py) to your Desktop. Then do `cd ~/Desktop`  in the Terminal. Then run the script like this : `python myscript.py`

Comment: I recommend going through basic bash tutorial to get more comfortable with the command line. For example http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-mac-os-x-command-line

Comment: Alternatively, you can open new Terminal, then `cd Desktop`, then type `python `, then type your commands

Comment: Yes! It worked! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the tesseract itself.

As it says in documentation 
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki#homebrew

```
    brew install tesseract
```

Also I'd recommend installing python through `brew` as well. 
That way you won't pollute system python installation.

And it's best to use virtualenv too.

Comment: Ok, I successfully downloaded tesseract and then tesseract-orc, but I still got the error " IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.png' ". What should I do from here?

Comment: Well, does `test.png` exist? It's hard to tell without seeing your code. Please add it to the question. Also please have a look at how to create [mcve]