# Pytesseract : "TesseractNotFound Error: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path", how do I fix this?

Tags: python, tesseract

I'm trying to run a basic and very simple code in python.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

im = Image.open("sample1.jpg")

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng')

print(text)
```

This is what it looks like, I have actually installed tesseract for windows through the installer. I'm very new to Python, and I'm unsure how to proceed?

Any guidance here would be very helpful. I've tried restarting my Spyder application but to no avail.

Comment: What isn't working? Can you add the errors you got in the question?

Answer (score 323, accepted):

I see steps are scattered in different answers. Based on my recent experience with this pytesseract error on Windows, writing different steps in sequence to make it easier to resolve the error:

**1**. Install tesseract using windows installer available at: https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

**2**. Note the tesseract path from the installation. Default installation path at the time of this edit was: `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR`. It may change so please check the installation path.

**3**. `pip install pytesseract`

**4**. Set the tesseract path in the script before calling `image_to_string`:

`pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'`

Comment: This worked for me!
If anyone else is facing problem with finding the "Tesseract-OCR" folder then please search in "C:\Program Files\" folder too

Comment: Had to restart my computer in order to get environment setting kick in

Comment: This answer is better than [the documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/), because the path to tesseract_cmd indeed needs to point to tesseract.exe. This is missing in the documentation.

Comment: pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'                                         
                                                                                                                                
This answer saved me from an important deadline on a Computer Vision - OCR Project Thanks a lot @Nafeez Quraishi :-)

Comment: @Barmaley why restart the pc. Which environment setting do you mean? I use Windows and choco.Apparently no environment path setting is needed. Seems to work because of step 4.

Comment: @Timo, the answer might of changed. You can either set this path directly in python or via system environment variables. So I went with the latter

Comment: If you're using `Textract` lib and getting error 127, it might be because it's missing Tesseract. Follow the steps on this answer but instead of setting the path on script (the pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd step) , set it as `your environment variable`

Comment: I am getting the such error on ubuntu system when I run the method image_to_string. How to solve in case of linux?

Comment: @XueQing check for the installation path of  Tesseract-OCR in your system. Replace this path with Windows path mentioned in the answer, it should work.

Comment: another option is after pip install, go to `Lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py` and edit `tesseract_cmd` directly.

Comment: A way that worked for me to find the path on Windows: First, go to "Add or Remove Programs" in settings and ATTEMPT to uninstall Tesseract. It will ask you if you want to uninstall Tesseract from this location, and you can copy that location down. Then, cancel uninstallation

Comment: instalation path is C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR

Comment: @mrbTT I use `Unstructured library`, `partition_pdf function`. And when I try to set `tesseract_cmd` in `pytesseract.py`, I get `CalledProcessError: Command '['/software/all/tesseract/4.1.0-GCCcore-11.2.0/bin/tesseract', '--version']' returned non-zero exit status 127`. Do you mean this error?

Comment: @JuliaKoncha, its been so long I don't even remember or have access to the code. Sorry I cant help you there.

Answer (score 138):

### First you should install binary:

#### On Linux

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libleptonica-dev tesseract-ocr tesseract-ocr-dev libtesseract-dev python3-pil tesseract-ocr-eng tesseract-ocr-script-latn
```

#### On Mac

```
brew install tesseract
```

#### On Windows

download binary from https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki. then add `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'` to your script.

### Then you should install python package using pip:

```
pip install tesseract
pip install tesseract-ocr
```

references:
https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/ (INSTALLATION section) and
https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Installation.html

Comment: UPDATE August 2021, for linux, I need to run `sudo apt-get install python3-pil tesseract-ocr libtesseract-dev tesseract-ocr-eng tesseract-ocr-script-latn`. The second reference (github) is not there anymore, I refered https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Installation.html

Comment: if you face this issue `tesseract: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtesseract.so.4: undefined symbol: pixaDisplayTiledInColumns
` or `Package tesseract-ocr-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
` then do this `sudo apt install libtesseract-dev libleptonica-dev liblept5`

Comment: @David17 Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (2022/03).

Comment: After following these steps, it installs tesseract version 4, how can we install version 5.2? Thanks

Comment: The update from @David17 worked for me (Linux Mint 05/2023).

Answer (score 37):

#### For Windows Only

1 - You need to have Tesseract OCR installed on your computer.

> get it from here.
> https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki
>
> Download the suitable version.

2 - Add Tesseract path to your System Environment. i.e. Edit system variables.

3 - Run `pip install pytesseract` and `pip install tesseract`

4 - **Add this line to your python script every time**

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/OCR/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'  # your path may be different
```

5 - Run the code.

Comment: Where to find the path for Linux?

Comment: @Pallavi this is a windows answer, so no Linux here please.. Step 2 seems not needed because of 4.

Comment: `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'`
 worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 28):

This error is because tesseract is not installed on your computer.

If you are using Ubuntu install tesseract using following command:

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

For mac:

```
brew install tesseract
```

Comment: this worked for me. had to do this after installing pytesseract

Answer (score 12):

From https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/ :

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'
# Include the above line, if you don't have tesseract executable in your PATH
# Example tesseract_cmd: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract'
```

Answer (score 8):

In windows:

```
pip install tesseract

pip install tesseract-ocr
```

and check the file which is stored in your system `usr/appdata/local/programs/site-pakages/python/python36/lib/pytesseract/pytesseract.py` file
and  compile the file

Comment: Notice that this doesn't work on windows, where you'll need to install the binary file (from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki) and add the line `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"` for tesseract to work.

Answer (score 6):

On Mac, you can install it like shown below. This works for me.

```
brew install tesseract
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue on Windows. 
I tried to update the environment variables for the path of tesseract which did not work.

What worked for me was to modify the pytesseract.py which can be found at the path `C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract` or usually in the `C:\Users\YOUR USER\APPDATA\Python`

I changed one line as per below:

```
#tesseract_cmd = 'tesseract' 
#tesseract_cmd = 'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
```

Note I had to put an extra `\` before tesseract as Python was interpreting same as `\t` and you will get the below error message:

> pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR  esseract.exe is not installed or it's not in your path

Answer (score 6):

**For Linux Distribution (Ubuntu)**

try

```
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
sudo apt install libtesseract-dev
```

Comment: This worked I also installed tesseract using pip3 install tesseract.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows 64 bits, just add the following to the PATH environment variable:
`"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR"` and it will work.

Answer (score 4):

**Anaconda Installation:**

Works on Mac, Linux, and Windows

[image]

[conda-forge/packages/tesseract 4.1.1](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tesseract)

Step 1:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tesseract
```

Step 2: Find Tesseract PATH if you haven't already

```
for r,s,f in os.walk("/"):
    for i in f:
        if "tesseract" in i:
            print(os.path.join(r,i))
```

For example, my Tesseract PATH is /anaconda/bin/tesseract

Step 3: Add tesseract to PATH

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/anaconda/bin/tesseract'
```

Answer (score 3):

you can install this package...
https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki
after that you should go this path C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\ tesseract.exe 
then run tesseract file.
I think this will help you...

Answer (score 3):

Step 1:

Install tesseract on your system as per the OS. 
Latest installers can be found at https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

Step 2:
Install the following dependency libraries using : 
   pip install pytesseract
   pip install opencv-python
   pip install numpy

Step 3: 
Sample code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string

# Path of working folder on Disk Replace with your working folder
src_path = "C:\\Users\\<user>\\PycharmProjects\\ImageToText\\input\\"
# If you don't have tesseract executable in your PATH, include the 
following:
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract- 
OCR/tesseract'
TESSDATA_PREFIX = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR'

def get_string(img_path):
    # Read image with opencv
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)

    # Convert to gray
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise
    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

    # Write image after removed noise
    cv2.imwrite(src_path + "removed_noise.png", img)

    #  Apply threshold to get image with only black and white
    #img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 31, 2)

    # Write the image after apply opencv to do some ...
    cv2.imwrite(src_path + "thres.png", img)

    # Recognize text with tesseract for python
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src_path + "thres.png"))

    # Remove template file
    #os.remove(temp)

    return result


print('--- Start recognize text from image ---')
print(get_string(src_path + "image.png") )

print("------ Done -------")
```

Comment: I had to do the step of setting the `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd` variable to my installation location on macOS. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 3):

I can solve it by updating the tesseract_cmd variable with the bin/tesseract path in the pytesseract.py file

Answer (score 3):

for me it worked by putting single quote

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd =r'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'
```

actually putting inside double quotes was automatically inserting unwanted chracter

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is happening because, even if Tesseract is correctly installed, you have not installed your language, as was my case. Fortunately this is very easy to fix, and I did not even need to mess with `tesseract_cmd`.

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr -y
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-spa -y
tesseract --list-langs
```

Note that in the second line we have specified `-spa` for Spanish.

If installation has been successful, you should get a list of your available languages, like:

```
List of available languages (3):
eng
osd
spa
```

I found this at [this blog post](https://parzibyte.me/blog/2019/05/18/instalar-tesseract-ocr-idioma-espanol-ubuntu/) (Spanish). There is also a post for [installation of Spanish language in Windows](https://parzibyte.me/blog/2019/05/11/instalar-tesseract-ocr-windows-10/) (not as easy apparently).

**Note**: since the question uses `lang = 'eng'`, it is likely this is not the answer in that specific case. But the same error may happen in this other situation, which is why I posted the answer here.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows in simple steps:

1. Download Windows version from https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki
2. Install
3. Write following in your .py file (check installed location)

   ```
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
    img_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))
   ```

Comment: Simple and it works ;-) Note only for windows env with python.

Comment: How would i Implement this if I was using google colab, I'm currently facing this issue

Answer (score 1):

You would be needing to install tesseract.

> https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki

Check out the above documentation on the installation.

Comment: Hi, I already tried doing that,  I installed from github using the installer for windows but it still doesn't quite work. Not sure why or what, I'm thinking it has to do with the path? I'll check out the wiki again

Comment: I got this error even though I've already installed pytesseract via pip.

Answer (score 1):

In windows, the command path must be redirected, for a default windows tesseract installation.

1. In 32 bit system, add in this line after import commands.

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
```

2. In 64 bit system, add this line instead.

```
 pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows users only:**

Install tesseract using:

```
pip install tesseract
```

and then add this line to your code, mind the "\"

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

It did work for me just by installing `tesseract` using `conda`.

```
conda install -c conda-forge tesseract
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# {Windows 10 instructions}
# before you use the script you need to install the dependence
# 1. download the tesseract from the official link:
#   https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki
# 2. install the tesseract
#   i chosed this path
#       *replace the user string in the below path with you name of user that you are using in your current machine
#       C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\
# 3. Install the  pillow for your python version
# * the best way for me is to install is this form(i'am using python3.7 version and in my CMD i run this version of python by     typing py -3.7):
# * if you are using another version of python first look how you start the python from you CMD
# * for some machine the run of python from the CMD is different
    # [examples]
    # =================================
    # PYTHON VERSION 3.7
    # python
    # python3.7
    # python -3.7
    # python 3.7
    # python3
    # python -3
    # python 3
    # py3.7
    # py -3.7
    # py 3.7
    # py3
    # py -3
    # py 3
    # PYTHON VERSION 3.6
    # python
    # python3.6
    # python -3.6
    # python 3.6
    # python3
    # python -3
    # python 3
    # py3.6
    # py -3.6
    # py 3.6
    # py3
    # py -3
    # py 3
    # PYTHON VERSION 2.7
    # python
    # python2.7
    # python -2.7
    # python 2.7
    # python2
    # python -2
    # python 2
    # py2.7
    # py -2.7
    # py 2.7
    # py2
    # py -2
    # py 2
    # ================================
# we are using pip to install the dependences
# because for me i start the python version 3.7 with the following line 
    # py -3.7
# open the CMD in windows machine and type the following line:
    # py -3.7 -m pip install pillow
# 4. Install the  pytesseract and tesseract for your python version
# * the best way for me is to install is this form(i'am using python3.7 version and in my CMD i run this version of python by     typing py -3.7):
# we are using pip to install the dependences
# open the CMD in windows machine and type the following lines:
    # py -3.7 -m pip install pytesseract
    # py -3.7 -m pip install tesseract


#!/usr/bin/python
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import os
import getpass

def extract_text_from_image(image_file_name_arg):

    # IMPORTANT
    # if you have followed my instructions to install this dependence in above text explanatin
    # for my machine is
    # if you don't put the right path for tesseract.exe the script will not work
    username = getpass.getuser()
    # here above line get the username for your machine automatically
    tesseract_exe_path_installation="C:\\Users\\"+username+"\\AppData\\Local\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=tesseract_exe_path_installation

# specify the direction of your image files manually or use line bellow if the images are in the script directory in     folder  images
    # image_dir="D:\\GIT\\ai_example\\extract_text_from_image\\images"
    image_dir=os.getcwd()+"\\images"
    dir_seperator="\\"
    image_file_name=image_file_name_arg
    # if your image are in different format change the extension(ex. ".png")
    image_ext=".jpg"
    image_path_dir=image_dir+dir_seperator+image_file_name+image_ext

    print("=============================================================================")
    print("image used is in the following path dir:")
    print("\t"+image_path_dir)
    print("=============================================================================")

    img=Image.open(image_path_dir)
    text=pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang="eng")
    print(text)

# change the name "image_1" whith the name without extension for your image name
# image_file_name_arg="image_1"
image_file_name_arg="image_2"
# image_file_name_arg="image_3"
# image_file_name_arg="image_4"
# image_file_name_arg="image_5"
extract_text_from_image(image_file_name_arg)

# ==================================
# CREATED BY: SHERIFI
# e-mail: sherif_co@yahoo.com
# git-link for script: https://github.com/sherifi/ai_example.git
# ==================================
```

Comment: Can you add text description to the snippet you posted?

Comment: I have add text inside the snippet for more easy access and completed answer

Answer (score 0):

```
For Ubuntu 18.04
```

If you are getting an error like

```
 tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path

 and 

 OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

That might be and issue with the swap memory allocation issue

You can check this answer allocating more swap memory Hope that helps :)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/920595/fallocate-fallocate-failed-text-file-busy-in-ubuntu-17-04?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

There are already many nice answers to this problem but I would like to share a wonderful site that I came across when I couldnt solve the 'TesseractNotFound Error: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path” Please refer this site: https://www.thetopsites.net/article/50655738.shtml

I realised that I got this error because I installed **pytesseract** with pip but forget to install the binary.
You are probably missing tesseract-ocr from your machine. Check the installation instructions here: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki

**On a Mac**, you can just install using homebrew:

`brew install tesseract`

It should run fine after that!

**Under Windows 10 OS environment**, the following method works for me:

1. Go to [this link](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki) and Download tesseract and install it. Windows version is available here: https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki
2. Find script file pytesseract.py from C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract and open it. Change the following code from **tesseract_cmd = 'tesseract'** to: **tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'**
   (This is the path where you install Tesseract-OCR so please check where you install it and accordingly update the path)
3. You may also need to add environment variable C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for UBUNTU Worked for me:**

Installed tesseract in ubuntu by following below link

https://medium.com/quantrium-tech/installing-tesseract-4-on-ubuntu-18-04-b6fcd0cbd78f

Later added traindata language to tessdata by following below link

[Tesseract running error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800730/tesseract-running-error)

Answer (score 0):

There looks to be an issue with the latest version of the pip module pytesseract=0.3.7.
I have downgraded it to pytesseract=0.3.6 and don't see the error.

Answer (score 0):

The above tips did not help me fix the problem, because the error specified in the section occurred when installing pytesseract (pycharm, python 2.7). The oddity was also that tesseract worked from the command line, so the installation was done correctly.

I was able to fix this problem by following these steps:

1. download pytesseract.py from the vault https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract
2. remove all syntax errors related to the difference in the interpreters (2.7 and 3.*), including the try catch methods
3. import the edited script into your program as a self-written one and configure the tesseract_cmd variable according to the recommendations in the repository.

Subsequently, the image-to-text translation function worked in python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I aleady tried this one on my raspberry pi. I just changed the path from this:

```
C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'
```

(Since, it is for windows) To this:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
```

Since, it is the path I see whenever I try to run this command:

```
pip3 show pytesseract
```

For better clarity here's the message.
[Command line here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rygyz.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing an same error while installing tesseract in windows.

Based my recent problem solving i am following thsese below steps

1. Install tesseract using windows installer available in the gievn link: https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki
2. Note the tesseract path from the installation. Default installation path at the time of this edit was: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR. It may change so please check the installation path.

After installations, still it is showing error or not installing error you are facing then press windows + R keys and run your file path (C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe) it wil work for me,

```
3. pip install pytesseract
```

[image: using command promt]

4. Set the tesseract path in the script before calling ```image_to_string:``
5. For windows file path -

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'C:\Program Files(x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
```

6. For installing opencv please - refer this [question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70941904/opencv-facing-an-error-for-tesseract-moule-not-found-even-after-installations/70941905#70941905)
7. *For linux installations*

```
$ sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
$ sudo apt install libtesseract-dev

$ tesseract --version
```

2.After running this command, you should something like this:

```
tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1 
 leptonica-1.75.3
```

3.Once your tesseract installation is successful, you can run the following command to check

```
$ tesseract --list-langs
```

4.You can expect the following output:

```
List of available languages (2):
eng 
osd
```

5.linux file path was given below

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'home/user/bin/tesseract'
```

Answer (score 0):

For Arch Linux, you may install the package `tesseract-data-<3_letter_language_prefix>`

For my case it was:
`<aur_helper> -S tesseract-data-eng`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Manjaro Arch Linux. To install `tesseract`, simply do

```bash
pamac install tesseract    # choose your own language pack
pip install pytesseract
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following command to install tesseract

`pip install tesseract`

Answer (score -3):

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
```

this helped in my case

Comment: The accepted answer mentions setting tesseract_cmd to the appropriate path, so I don't think this answer adds anything.