# Tesseract Not Found in Terminal

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have a problem with tesseract (I'm working with Pycharm).
When I run the script everything is ok. But when I define a method and run it in the terminal, it raises an error:

```
TesseractNotFoundError: C:\Users\nom_utilisateur\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path
```

The problem is, why did it show a path that I didn't define in the beginning of the script as tesseract's path? Here is my script's head:

```
from PIL import Image
import re
import argparse
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
from pytesseract import Output
import sys
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'
```

my method:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     img_path = sys.argv[1]
     corrections_file = sys.argv[2]
     output_img_file = sys.argv[3]
     output_text_file = sys.argv[4]
     demo(img_path, corrections_file, output_img_file, output_text_file)
```

And also a screenchot of the results in Pycharm's Terminal
[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53672281/5179465), the default install path for Tesseract is `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR`. `pytesseract` needs the actual tesseract executable, thus you need to set it as `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'<wherever tesseract is installed>\tesseract.exe'`.