# Detectron2LayoutModel: model_final.pth not found

Tags: python, detectron, layout-parser

I am encountering the following error when attempting to use Detectron2LayoutModel using the code found in the installation documentation:

```
AssertionError: Checkpoint /root/.torch/iopath_cache/s/6icw6at8m28a2ho/model_final.pth not found!
```

I initially used:

```
pip install layoutparser torchvision && pip install "detectron2@git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git@v0.5#egg=detectron2"
```

Followed by running the following code:

```
import layoutparser as lp
model = lp.Detectron2LayoutModel('lp://HJDataset/faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/config')
```

which produced the error:

```
PIL.Image.LINEAR no longer exists
```

From https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/issues/5010, I used the following install to correct that error.

```
pip install 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git@ff53992b1985b63bd3262b5a36167098e3dada02'
```

but now have the following error:

```
AssertionError: Checkpoint /root/.torch/iopath_cache/s/6icw6at8m28a2ho/model_final.pth not found!
```

and am having trouble getting past this one. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68094922/pytorch-throws-oserror-on-detectron2layoutmodel This solved the path issues for me

Answer (score 0):

When you examine the directory mentioned in the error message (in this instance, it's located at `/root/.torch/iopath_cache/s/dgy9c10wykk4lq4/`), you might discover a file named `model_final.pth?dl=1`. To resolve the issue, simply rename the file and remove the ?dl=1 portion. This serves as a temporary solution until a more permanent fix is implemented.