# Tesseract not working in python but does in cmd

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have installed tesseract-OCR and also added to path and if I try to check the version in the cmd it works.

[CMD Tesseract version command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spKmk.jpg)

I also tried to use python on the cmd to see if pytesseract works fine and it seems to be working

[CMD Python tesseract import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLpd8.jpg)

but if I import it in a python script it can't find tesseract

[Error message in python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A33nM.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: that is all the code I just import it and it display this error, I just finished installing it

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50951955/pytesseract-tesseractnotfound-error-tesseract-is-not-installed-or-its-not-i). Try the answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51396975/11070916

Comment: tesseract is executable by the path, look first screenshot. I also already tried and it does not work but I will add that screen too

Comment: First of all screenshots are frowned upon. Full text of code and error messages is preferred. Possibly, you need to tell  pytesseract where the executable is with `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'`.