# AttributeError: module 'pytesseract.pytesseract' has no attribute 'pytesseract'

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to use pytesseract to read text from images. This is my code-

```
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd='C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
img = cv2.imread("download.png")
print('image is',img)
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
gry = cv2.resize(gry, (w*2, h*2))
cls = cv2.morphologyEx(gry, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, None)
thr = cv2.threshold(cls, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
# pytesseract.tesseract_cmd='C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
txt = image_to_string(thr)
print(txt)
```

I am getting the following error-

AttributeError: module 'pytesseract.pytesseract' has no attribute 'pytesseract'.

I have already downloaded the tesseract windows binary and specified the correct path. I have already downloaded pytesseract and tesseract using pip. Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: Are you using an environment? anaconda, venv, etc?

Comment: @Alessandro No I'm not using any environment

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53672281/13147413

Comment: Thanks but I have followed this exact procedure as shown in  my code. Yet it is giving that error. I had already gone through these articles before posting the query. Any other ideas?

Comment: The most stupid one: try uninstall and reinstall pytesseract.

Comment: One extra backslash in the path did the trick

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytesseract : "TesseractNotFound Error: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path", how do I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50951955/pytesseract-tesseractnotfound-error-tesseract-is-not-installed-or-its-not-i)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to import pytesseract:

```
import pytesseract
```

Comment: Thanks but now Im facing this error,even though I have taken all  the steps required.
raise TesseractNotFoundError()
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR  esseract.exe is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.