# How to setup pytesseract path in amazon sagemaker notebook (cloud)?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, python-tesseract

I have installed pytesseract using `pip install pytesseract` in sagemaker notebook now I need to setup tesseract path `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'home/studio-lab-user/.conda/envs/studiolab/bin/tesseract/tesseract.exe'`

Now how to do it? I tried to bring locally installed Tesseract-OCR folder to the cloud sagemaker notebook and given the path but still it is says tesseract was not installed or available at given path

So how to setup tesseract path on sagemaker notebook. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried steps in question/comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74661785/running-pytesseract-in-sagemaker-jupyter-notebook ?

Comment: But that is for offline. If I want to setup in cloud instance then what is the procedure.