# pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError in databricks notebook

Tags: python, databricks, python-tesseract

Im trying to extract the text data from img file in databricks notebook
I have installed below libraries using pip command:
%pip install pytesseract tesseract pillow --upgrade

**but it didn't work and threw below error
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.**

I then installed below the libraries using the libraries section of cluster in databricks:

- pillow
- pytesseract
- tesseract

But this didn't work too.

later i ran the below shell command in Databricks notebook cell:

`%sh apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr`

This command gave me below error:
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Here is my code which i want to run in my databricks notebook:

`img=img_path img_gray = img.convert('L') text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_gray)`

I want the code to extract the textual data accurately from images
Please let me know where am i doing mistake?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53672281/12621346)  answer your question? You need also a tesseract installation. I don’t know, if this is allowed on databricks.