# Pytesseract No such file or directory error

Tags: python, image, text, pycharm, tesseract

First of all I did everything mentioned here [pytesseract-no such file or directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741563/pytesseract-no-such-file-or-directory-error)

Still doesn't work. Now I'm using Pycharm IDE with following code:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import subprocess

im = Image.open('test.png')
im.show()
subprocess.call(['tesseract','test.png','out'])
print pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png'))
```

- im.show() opens the image successfully.
- subprocess.call() with tesseract test.png out also extracts the text
  from the image..
- but pytesseract.image_to_string() fails.

I don't get it. Why I am able to use tesseract in shell but not in python. And in python I can open same image but when used with tesseract Image can't be found.

Below you can see the error output.

```
 File "/home/hamza-c/Schreibtisch/Android/JioShare/orc.py", line 7, in <module>
    print pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('/home/hamza-c/Schreibtisch/Android/JioShare/test.png'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 162, in image_to_string
    config=config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 95, in run_tesseract
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1340, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: I had the same problem and found the solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741563/pytesseract-no-such-file-or-directory-error)

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I solved my own question.

```
im = Image.open('test.png')
print pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
```

It's still unclear why it works when a reference is passed but not directly when I try to open image inside the parameter.

Answer (score 5):

I tested the code you mentioned in your question. It works fine. I was facing the same error

> *No such file or directory found*

The problem was the directory containing 'tesseract.exe' was not added to the environment Variable. You should be able to run command 'tesseract' in command prompt.

if tesseract is not installed you can download it from [tesseract](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki) 
  [1](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki): https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki and for windows use third party installer available [here](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki)

Comment: How to add to the environment variable? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need install tesseract ,if your os is centos, please enter

```
yum install tesseract
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following command and it worked for me:

```
brew install tesseract
```