# Why does this file I/O code not work under Eclipse/ PyDev but works in terminal?

Tags: python, terminal, pydev

I have working code in which I use tesseract to extract data from image file, as follows:

```
if src:
    driver.get(src)
    driver.save_screenshot('/Users/username/script/' + 'test.png')
    image_name = 'test.png'
    im = Image.open(image_name)
    image_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
    print '\nImage Text:\t', image_text
```

This code snippet works without any error in Mac terminal when I execute code but when I do the same in Eclipse using PyDev, it throws an error:

```
Exception:  [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

when trying to execute the line:

```
im = Image.open(image_name)
```

Why is this happening in Eclipse?

**UPDATE**: Since my code seemed funky to few people, I have changed it as following but the issue still remains (runs perfectly fine on mac terminal but Eclipse keeps giving me same error)

```
if src:
    driver.get(src)
    image_name = 'test.png'
    image_path = os.path.realpath(image_name)
    driver.save_screenshot(image_path)

    # read chart data from image
    im = Image.open(image_path)
```

Comment: I guess the image is not in the working directory. You can adapt the working directory in the run configuration or use an absolute file name (with path).

Comment: Can you try with complete path to read image.

Image.open("/Users/username/script/test.png")

Comment: @KlausD. image is indeed in the same working directory and that is why it would work in terminal?

Comment: @SunilT I get the same exception when using the full path `image_name = '/Users/username/script/test.png'`

Comment: Follow this post once-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765227/python-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @ShoaibAkhtar I tried your suggestion but ended up with same error  `curr_dir = os.getcwd()
                        temp_name = 'test.png'
                        image_name = os.path.join(curr_dir, temp_name)
                        im = Image.open(image_name)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally figured out the issue by using traceback as suggested by @Fabio. It was NOT related to image file not present in the current directory but problem with not finding tesseract in path.

Inside pytesseract.py file, it reads:

```
# CHANGE THIS IF TESSERACT IS NOT IN YOUR PATH, OR IS NAMED DIFFERENTLY
tesseract_cmd = 'tesseract'
```

Note that changing the pytesseract.py file directly is not a good idea but in whatever file you are importing pytesseract, add the following line (path to tesseract will depend on your particular machine...in mac I was able to find path by using `which` command: `which tesseract`)

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/usr/local/bin/tesseract'
```

Comment: @JonahGraham Thanks, I found my fix already and posted it above

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit strange... you save with a path and then just use the image_name afterwards.

Try it with the following code:

```
import os

filename = '/path/to/the/image.png'
driver.save_screenshot(filename)
if not os.path.exists(filename):
    raise AssertionError("Image: %s does not exist" % (filename,))
Image.open(filename)
```

if it doesn't work, paste the full contents of the stacktrace.

Comment: I tried with your code and the stacktrace is still the same `Exception: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: I have updated my code based on your comment (see above) but still the same exception

Comment: In your new code, you didn't add the os.path.exists() call I outlined... Also, please post the **full** contents of the exception, not just the final bit.

Comment: That is the full content of the exception, please see the screenshot in the link [here](https://expirebox.com/download/413e2ce0ad81f6d1db90d00e9f003644.html). I have also included you os.path.exists() call.

Comment: Humm, in your except clause, you shouldn't print the exception as you're doing, rather, print it as: `import traceback;traceback.print_exc()` in your exception handler to get the **full** stack trace -- PyDev actually has a template for that, so, you can write `printexc` Ctrl+Space and get those contents written for you ;)

Comment: thanks for the useful info. I guess I would use traceback more often in my code. Traceback was long so I could not post it here but it is same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741563/pytesseract-no-such-file-or-directory-error) so looks like I need to change value for setting config in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py`

Comment: Thanks again, traceback was very useful. Problem was fixed by explicitly defining the path of tesseract as mentioned in pytesseract package `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/usr/local/bin/tesseract'`